# Problema ao atualizar appcompat-v7

Tags: android, gradle

Olá

Tenho um projeto que está utilizando a versão `23.1.0` da biblioteca  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`.

Fui atualizar para  a 23.1.1 e ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
 Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
 Install Repository and sync project
 Show in File
 Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Tentei atualizar pelo Structure dialog. Ele acha a biblioteca, inclui no Gradle, mas na hora de compilar ocore o mesmo erro!

Atualizei todos as SDK's e mesmo assim o erro persiste!

Alguém já teve este tipo de problema?

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: O arquivo baixado pode estar corrompido, tente excluir e baixar de novo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalado o Android Studio, e tudo voltou a funcionar!

Sugestão do [Androiderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4437/androiderson).